# lokale Präpositionen

Tags: preposition

Ich habe im Internet die folgende Liste gefunden:
[image: Erste Seite Präpositionenliste]

und hier die zweite Seite:
[image: Zweite Seite Präpositionenliste]

Ich interessiere mich für die Systematik dieser Liste bzw. ich zweifle daran, ob die letzten 2 Zeilen der Seite 2 wirklich auf diese Liste gehören.

Diese Liste suggeriert, dass man in der ersten Spalte jeweils eine Frage mit *woher?* stellen kann. Und dass man in der zweiten Spalte und in der dritten Spalte jeweils eine Frage mit *wo?* bzw. *wohin?* stellen kann.

Beispiele:

- 1 Zeile 1 Blatt:
  Woher kommen sie? Antwort: Sie kommen aus Europa.
  Wo leben sie? Antwort: Sie leben in Europa.
  Wohin fahren sie? Antwort: Sie fahren nach Europa.
- 1 Zeile 2 Blatt:
  Woher kommt sie gerade? Antwort: Sie kommt gerade aus der Kirche.
  Wo wartet sie auf mich? Antwort: Sie wartet in der Kirche auf mich.
  Wohin geht sie? Antwort: Sie geht in die Kirche.

… So ist diese Liste aufgebaut. Denn das funktioniert mit jeder Zeile.

Wirklich? Funktioniert die *woher*-Frage auch mit den letzten 2 Zeilen des zweiten Blattes? Ich habe versucht auch hier *Woher*-Fragen zu bilden:

- Woher springt das Kind? Antwort: Das Kind springt vom Stuhl.
  → Ich denke das ist kein korrektes Deutsch. Oder?
- Woher nimmt sie den Kalender? Antwort: Sie nimmt den Kalender von der Wand.
  → Ich denke, das ist auch kein korrektes Deutsch. Oder?

**Was ist meine konkrete Frage:**
Ich suche für die letzten 2 Zeilen zwei *woher*-Fragen in korrektem Deutsch. Diese muss es ja geben, denn das ist der Systematik dieses Blattes geschuldet.

Comment: Probier's mal mit "von wo?", einer umgangssprachlichen Frage nach der Richtung, aus der etwas auf einen zukommt. *Woher* und *wohin* dürften hier eher zu verstehen sein als "Bewegung auf mich zu, Frage nach der Herkunft" bzw. "Bewegung von mir weg, Frage nach dem Ziel" als **wörtlich**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Systematik ist insofern korrekt, als in der ersten Spalte tatsächlich ausschließlich Beispiele für Sätze stehen, in denen der erwähnte Ort der Ausgangspunkt einer Bewegung ist. Und nach diesem Ort fragt man üblicherweise mit »woher«.

Allerdings ist im Beispiel der vorletzten Zeile (»Das Kind springt vom Stuhl.«) die Frage »woher« tatsächlich stilistisch unpassend. »Von wo« würde hier besser passen.

Im Beispiel der letzten Zeile (»Sie nimmt den Kalender von der Wand«) kann ich an der Frage

> Woher nimmt sie den Kalender?

aber nichts Störendes empfinden. Für mich ist diese Frage vollkommen in Ordnung. Aber auch hier könnte man stattdessen fragen

> Von wo nimmt sie den Kalender?

Der Ausdruck »von wo« ist ein Synonym für »woher«. Ohne jetzt jedes Beispiel aus der Liste dahingehend überprüft zu haben, wage ich jetzt zu behaupten, dass man die Woher-Frage in jedem Fall auch mit »von wo« stellen könnte. Manchmal wird die eine Variante stilistisch besser passen, manchmal die andere.

Comment: Wäre  esi n einem Unterrichtsmaterial geeignet "von wo" zu schreiben? Ich dachte dies wäre mit "mit was" und ähnliche umgangssprachlichen Konstruktionen zu vergleichen.  Warum nicht "wovon" statt "von wo"?

Comment: @Beta: Nein, »wovon« und »von wo« sind nicht austauschbar, sie haben unterschiedliche Bedeutung. Beispiel: »Wovon hast du genascht? - Ich habe vom Kuchen genascht.« Aber: »Von wo hast du den Kuchen geholt? - Ich habe den Kuchen aus der Küche geholt.« »Wovon« kann aber oft durch »von was« ersetzt werden: »Von was hast du genascht? - Ich habe vom Kuchen genascht.« In einem Lehrbuch würde ich die Spalte mit »wovon / von wo« übertiteln. »Mit was« wird oft als Synonym für »womit« verwendet: »Womit/mit was hast du die Brote belegt?«